# 'ld' complains 'XCOFF32 members are ignored in 64-bit mode' even though the library is XCOFF64. Why?

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors, ld, aix

I am linking using 'ld' on the AIX machine using OBJECT_MODE 64.

I get a strange warning 'XCOFF32 members are ignored in 64-bit mode' when linking with a 64 bit archive.

> ld: 0711-737 WARNING: Archive member
>   /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/8.2.0/pthread/ppc64/libsupc++.a[array_type_info.o]:
>           XCOFF32 members are ignored in 64-bit mode.

I ensured that the object file in the archive is XCOFF64 using the following technique:

I copied the archive into a temporary folder and extracted the contents:

```
cp /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/8.2.0/pthread/ppc64/libsupc++.a ./
ar x libsupc++.a
ls
array_type_info.o        ...
```

And used the 'file' command to verify the type of object file in question.

```
file array_type_info.o
array_type_info.o: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

Why does the linker throw this warning even though the archive/objects are XCOFF64?

Comment: That *.a archive might very vell contain two elements with the same name but different bittyness. Try this: `ar -X32_64 tv libsupc++.a`

Comment: I'll try that and see